# jQuery performance: hide() vs is(':visible') - which is faster?

Tags: jquery, performance

I have multiple dropdown boxes which drop when their link is clicked.
The boxes have the possibility to overlap if they are open at the same time.

Is it faster to query whether the element is visible `$('#box').is(':visible')` and then if the box is visible to hide it `$('#box').hide()` or just to tell it to hide regardless?

For arguments sake, lets say that 50% of the time the box is open and 50% of the time it is already hidden.

TL;DR

Is this:

```
$("#box1-link").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#box2').is(':visible')) {
        $('#box2').hide();
    }

    $('#box1').slideDown(200, function() {
    });
});
```

or this:

```
$("#box1-link").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#box2').hide();

    $('#box1').slideDown(200, function() {
    });
});
```

faster in the long run? - assuming that box2 is hidden 50% of the time that the link is clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

(August 2013) It looks like with the changes to jQuery, simply calling `hide` may not be the fastest option anymore (though it's probably still preferable, for brevity, and clarity). Take a look at this [updated benchmark test case](http://jsperf.com/check-element-viz-before-hide/3).

---

First, it should be noted that the runtime effect of this will be infinitesimal, and you would be hard-pressed to create a situation in which this would be the bottle-neck in your performance.

The second approach, however, is likely to be faster simply because it already has that `if` check built-in to it anyway:

```
// ... line 7996 (jQuery 1.8.1):
if (!values[index] && display !== "none") {
    jQuery._data(elem, "olddisplay", display);
}​
// ...
```

In other words, the function is only executed on the DOM element if it doesn't already have `display: none`. There's could still be a possibility that the `.is()` method manages to be a little faster since it avoids fewer method calls, but a look at the method itself will quickly dispel these fears:

```
// ...line 6804:
return !!selector && (
    typeof selector === "string" ?
        // If this is a positional/relative selector, check membership in the returned set
        // so $("p:first").is("p:last") won't return true for a doc with two "p".
        rneedsContext.test(selector) ?
            jQuery(selector, this.context).index(this[0]) >= 0 :
            jQuery.filter(selector, this).length > 0 : 
        this.filter(selector).length > 0);​
// ...
```

In short, the second is faster -- [**jsPerf test-case**](http://jsperf.com/check-element-viz-before-hide).

Comment: Note that in jsPerf the second option outperforms the other in both cases, when the element is initially hidden or when it is initially visible

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought would happen. The question was definitely more academic in nature (like you said, the performance differences are tiny), but it helps me understand the way Jquery fires some methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think its faster to hide it always. Another option could be to create a reference for the box example var b = $('#box2'). rather than calling $('#box2'). I think this would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .toggle() function for this too.

```
var $box1 = $('#box1'),
    $box2 = $('#box2');
$('.majorDiv').on('click', '#box1-link', function(e){

  var $this = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();

  $box1.fadeToggle();
  $box2.slideDown(200, function(){
    //do stuff here
  });

});
```