# jQuery - show/hide - check if already set

Tags: jquery, micro-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery performance: hide() vs is(':visible') - which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312047/jquery-performance-hide-vs-isvisible-which-is-faster)

Does it make sense to check (by own condition) if element is already hidden before calling jQuery.hide() function? (*and analogy with jQuery.show()*)

Reading function source code, it seems to me, it run over, regardless of element property. Is more *time expensive* do check or let function set atributes over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kinds of questions are always best answered with an actual performance test and the jsperf system makes it pretty easy to test.

In a surprise to me, if the desired style is already set, then it does seem to save some performance cycles (in Chrome and Firefox) to check first before setting it.

You can see a number of different combinations here: http://jsperf.com/hide-vs-check

As the simplest comparison between these two options:

```
elem.style.display = "none";
elem.style.display = "none";
```

and

```
elem.style.display = "none";
if (elem.style.display !== "none") {
    elem.style.display = "none";
}
```

The second option is a slight bit faster.  This suggests that setting the style, even when it's already set to that value still has a significant cost and it does save time to avoid setting it when it's not needed.

---

Or the jQuery version of the two options:

```
elem.style.display = "none";
elem$.hide()
```

and

```
elem.style.display = "none";
if (elem$.css("display") !== "none") {
    elem$.hide();
}
```

Still shows that the second option is faster when the desired state is already set.

---

But, if the state needs to be changed, then the extra test does (obviously) slow you down.  The first option here is faster than the second one because the condition just costs extra time if the condition evaluates to true:

```
elem.style.display = "block";
elem$.hide()
```

and

```
elem.style.display = "block";
if (elem$.css("display") !== "none") {
    elem$.hide();
}
```

Comment: it seems much much faster to use elem.style.display = "none"; than .hide() - I had thousands of elements and I used $.each after making an array with $('.items').get()

Answer (score 1):

It is more time consuming to check the attributes. First jQuery has to find the elements and then check all of the following:

- They have a CSS display value of `none`.
- They are form elements with `type="hidden"`.
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

In the other case when setting the attribute it's just 2 steps - find the element and assign (or overwrite) a property.

Comment: I can write own condition. Sthg like `if css.attr("display")=='hidden'` then is only one step. Or?

Comment: @JirkaKopřiva - `style.display` cannot be accessed with `css.attr("display")`.

Comment: When I try to test your hypothesis in jsperf, I get the opposite answer.  It does save time to check the value (in Chrome) when the value is already set to the desired value.